# Compressing and decompressing data while uploading and downloading data from server

Tags: iphone, compression

In my app, I am downloading and uploading huge data(ie images)from server, which is time consuming. So I was thinking is there any way to compress data while uploading and decompress it while downloading?I googled it but I found solution which will scale or reduce size of image, I do not want to change size of original image. Is there any way to compress and decompress the image?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Images in common formats (unless bitmaps) are already compressed, so there won't be much gain in compress them again.

Comment: like @Luis said, images are already compressed, for other kind, like huge text files, you could try to divide your upload into parts, like 1MB, and zip those parts (there exists many zip libraries available for iOS, just google it)

Comment: Thanks for response, I will check for zip libraries.